# How to use NetworKit as a library in OMNeT++?

Tags: c++, omnet++, networkit

I am trying to build the C++ Core of NetworKit and I would like to use it as a library in OMNeT++. I followed the instructions from the README file to build the code with `cmake` and `make all`. Then, I tried to follow the instructions from the *Use NetworKit as a library* section, but the examples presented there are not consistent with the source code. In particular, the directory `NetworKit/graph` does not contain the `Graph.h` file. There is a `Graph.hpp` file, but in another directory. Also, the `LibDemo.cpp` file is missing. Is the README file outdated or I am missing something here?

EDIT
This is an update to my post above. Apparently the README file is not up to date. In any case, I built the C++ Core of NetworKit. I included the library in my OMNeT++ application as follows:
`#include <graph/Graph.hpp>`
In OMNeT++, in my project `Properties | OMNeT++ | Makemake`, and then selecting `src | Options | Custom`, I added the following:

```
INCLUDE_PATH += -I/path/to/networkit/include/networkit
LIBS += -L/path/to/networkit/build_lib -lnetworkit
```

When I build my OMNeT++ project, I get the following error:

```
/path/to/networkit/include/networkit/graph/../Globals.hpp:42:14: error: expected unqualified-id 
const double PI = 2.0*std::acos(0);
             ^
/path/to/omnetpp-5.4.1/include/omnetpp/simkerneldefs.h:47:19: note: expanded from macro 'PI'
#define PI        3.141592653589793
                  ^
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Put a `#undef PI` before the `const double PI`. Alternatively comment out one of them (probably the const double).

Comment: And please don't put multiple unrelated questions into a question, make a new one. (how would an aceeptable answer look like? does everybody have to answer all the parts?)

Comment: The second option (commenting the line) triggers compilation errors in NetworKit. The first one works fine, I am able to build both NetworKit and my OMNeT++ project. However, when launching the application I get this error:  `<!> Error: Cannot load library '../../src//libhetvnet.so': libnetworkit.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` . Any idea why?

Comment: I solved this problem by copying `libnetworkit.so` in the same directory of my `omnetpp.ini` file. I acknowledge this might not be the most elegant solution, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct, the documentation is out of date, `LibDemo.cpp` was deleted here: https://github.com/kit-parco/networkit/commit/a5b2c1f0c9336e783c8fb0cd956326d960451914

If you want an older version where this part of the doc is still valid, that would be version 4.2 which is the last version with this file. Somebody made a clone of that version here for some reason: https://github.com/SharafMohamed/NetworKit

Comment: Thank you. I went forward and stepped into another problem. I will update my initial post.